# BQ command line how to use "--noflatten_results" option to have nested fields

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to query table with nested and repeated fields, using bq command line give me flattened result while i need to get result as the original format.

[image]

The orignal format is looking like

```
{
    "fields": [
      {
        "fields": [
          {
            "mode": "REQUIRED",
            "name": "version",
            "type": "STRING"
          },
          {
            "mode": "REQUIRED",
            "name": "hash",
            "type": "STRING"
          },
          {
            "mode": "REQUIRED",
            "name": "header",
            "type": "STRING"
          },
          {
            "name": "organization",
            "type": "STRING"
          },
          {
            "mode": "REQUIRED",
            "name": "date",
            "type": "TIMESTAMP"
          },
          {
            "mode": "REQUIRED",
            "name": "encoding",
            "type": "STRING"
          },
          {
            "mode": "REQUIRED",
            "name": "message_type",
            "type": "STRING"
          },
          {
            "mode": "REQUIRED",
            "name": "receiver_code",
            "type": "STRING"
          },
          {
            "mode": "REQUIRED",
            "name": "sender_code",
            "type": "INTEGER"
          },
          {
            "mode": "REQUIRED",
            "name": "segment_separator",
            "type": "STRING"
          },
          {
            "fields": [
              {
                "fields": [
                  {
                    "name": "name",
                    "type": "STRING"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "description",
                    "type": "STRING"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "value",
                    "type": "STRING"
                  },
                  {
                    "fields": [
                      {
                        "name": "name",
                        "type": "STRING"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "description",
                        "type": "STRING"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "value",
                        "type": "STRING"
                      }
                    ],
                    "mode": "REPEATED",
                    "name": "composite_elements",
                    "type": "RECORD"
                  }
                ],
                "mode": "REPEATED",
                "name": "elements",
                "type": "RECORD"
              },
              {
                "name": "description",
                "type": "STRING"
              },
              {
                "mode": "REQUIRED",
                "name": "name",
                "type": "STRING"
              }
            ],
            "mode": "REPEATED",
            "name": "segments",
            "type": "RECORD"
          },
          {
            "mode": "REQUIRED",
            "name": "message_identifier",
            "type": "INTEGER"
          },
          {
            "mode": "REQUIRED",
            "name": "element_separator",
            "type": "STRING"
          },
          {
            "name": "composite_element_separator",
            "type": "STRING"
          }
        ],
        "mode": "REPEATED",
        "name": "messages",
        "type": "RECORD"
      },
      {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "syntax",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "encoding",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "file_name",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "size",
        "type": "INTEGER"
      }
    ]
  }
```

So how to export (locally) data with the nesting representation ?

**[EDIT]**

Export to Google to have nested representation

It's seem the only solution to export the nesting representation it's to export to table then extract to Google Storage and finally download the file.

```
bq query --destination_table=DEV.EDI_DATA_EXPORT --replace \
--allow_large_results --noflatten_results \
"select * from DEV.EDI_DATA where syntax='EDIFACT' " \
 && bq extract --destination_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON DEV.EDI_DATA_EXPORT gs://mybucket/data.json \
 && gsutil cp gs://mybucket/data.json .
```

It's surprising to me...

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use `-noflatten_results` you also have to use `--allow_large_results` and `--destination_table`. This stores the non-flattened results in a new table.

Comment: I need to have the json locally (web app) :)

Comment: after saving the results to a new table, you can JSON export it :)

Comment: I will update my OP, feel free to comment my answer.

Comment: if this is not convenient enough, you can always add or star a feature request: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list?q=label:Feature-Request